# Anarcho-Communism distribution of wealth

Tags: government, communism, anarchism, society

How would a society based on [anarcho-communism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-communism), or even communism without state, distribute the wealth so people could buy food, leisure products and other varied items. Who would distribute the currency, if there is any currency at all. Would there be banks? Who would manage them?

If everybody has the same equal amount of wealth then it limits liberty, because some things cost more than other things. If not, if somebody has more than another there would arise jealousy and hatred.

Comment: There is no such thing as anarcho-communism, since communists want the implementation of a proletarian dictatorship, anarchists do not want any dictatorship or concentration of power at all. You may be thinking about a) anarcho-socialism b) anarcho-unionism c) the socialist society that is supposed to be implemented when the proletarian dictatorship is obsolete (cf Karl Marx; the dictatorship is in theory not supposed to last forever)

Comment: @user5751924 I refer you to https://goo.gl/gExhfd and https://goo.gl/QhNYiZ

Comment: Agree with @user5751924. The practical application of communism on a wide scale requires a very powerful central state to own and order the collective community. Anarchists are by definition against such a powerful state. Maybe you should research pre-1948 kibbutzism, which is kind of a communist/socialist microcosm without an effective national government.

Comment: @guerrier #toc31 (Chapter 29: Consumption and Exchange) from your first link seems to cover a fair portion of this stuff, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt You're right. My bad. I haven't reached that part. I wanted to short-circuit the answer.

Comment: That brand of political thinking is usually referred to as "revolutionary anarcho-socialism": we do a revolution, then build an anarcho-socialist society right away.

Comment: @user5751924 can you point me in the right direction of "revolutionary anarcho-socialism". I don't seem to find it on a search query. Is it by another name?

Comment: Anarcho-Socialism != Anarcho communism

Comment: @user5751924 actually the dictatorship of the proletariat is just meant to be a transitional phase to "true" communism: `that this dictatorship, itself, constitutes no more than a transition to the abolition of all classes and to a classless society` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictatorship_of_the_proletariat#Karl_Marx

Comment: @SJuan76 - With the problem being that the Dictator never feels the time is right to let go of the absolute power.

Comment: There is a disconnect with some people believing that communism is a type of government.  Communism is a form of economy not government.  Anarchy would be the government type with a communist economy meaning that there is no private ownership of anything everything belongs to the community.

Comment: @SoylentGray - while you are correct; the reason for that disconnect is because it is not obvious how communism can work with a form of government that's NOT a dictatorship, in practice. No matter what Marx theorized. Only a dictatorship can stop someone from keeping the tools of production they themselves make. Hmmm... now that you mention it, it's something I am curious enough about to ask a question.

Comment: @user4012 Marx was talking about a successor to industrialized capitalism so it's not about "tools" but rather machines and factories that already required the collective work of lots of people and not the artisan who build their own tools. And that conversely aren't protected by the individual but where the individual employs police and military to protect property on their behalf. So it already required collective efforts to create them and it does require force to uphold ownership relations that do not reflect that.

Comment: @SoylentGray It's not really that you can separate the economical from the political and vice versa. Like lots of politics is concerned with economic matters and economic special interest groups regularly try to influence political decisions.

Comment: @haxor789 - You can the people who run the system choose not to.

Comment: @SoylentGray They couldn't even if they wanted to.

Comment: @user5751924 Well, that is only one way to achieve communism. I explained this in a previous answer, but the dictatorship of the proletariat is only one method for achieving communism. Communists  - even in Marxism - are given a bunch of different methods to potentially achieve true communism from the dictatorship to global revolution to simply burning down the state once you have enough technology to implement communism on a large scale. A lot of anarcho-communists tend to choose the non-dictator options.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it would mirror Communal living that you see in areas like [here](http://lostvalley.org/about-the-community/) or [here](http://www.bruderhof.com/en/topics/intentional-community).  With the exception that these communities are forced to live within the legal structure of their host states.   In a more anarcho-Communism society those limits would not exist so those things that are currently prohibited to these communities, like the cultivation and processing of certian plants, would be up to the community to police.

At the same time each community would be responsible for their own protection.  The reason being that just because your society decided in a non violence and aggression policy does not mean that those people who do not subscribe to those policies will not exist.  Another thing to consider is that it is possible that people who would prey on those outside of your community could use your community as sanctuary.

These are the points that tend to break down any anarchy based societal group.  The reason is these are the points that breed corruption into communism.  The need for defense means the need for a leader for that defense organization.  The need to discipline leads to the need for a set of rules, but the majority can choose to side step the rules in special cases, which leads an group of "More Equals" which leads the community towards statism and away from the anarchy based society.

Also there is no personal wealth in a communist economy.  Everything is shared and needs are provided with excess consumables shared in an as equal as possible basis.  Any accumulation of wealth would belong to the community not any individual.  This excess would be traded with other communities for items of use to the community.  So any wealth, ie something you can accumulate and not have an immediate need for, would stay in the community stores until needed.

Answer (score 1):

To explain things better, there is a community that practices anarcho-communism showing that the idea can work - at least on a small scale. It has a population of around 2,626 people according to *The Municipal Register of Spain 2018*. The town has an economy where everything works with a farming cooperative with 2,650 workers. The workers [collectively](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/26/world/europe/26spain.html?_r=1&pagewanted=all) work to grow a bunch of different crops from artichokes to hot peppers, broccoli, and wheat. If you work, you are able to get a house without a mortgage, but you are [not allowed to sell your house](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/26/world/europe/26spain.html?_r=1&pagewanted=all) and the homes are a colony of neat homes with 3 bedrooms, one bathroom, and a 100 square meter garden for each. The land for the homes is the communal property that is supposed to have houses built on them based on the needs of people joining the communities.